# ¿Cómo funciona este código para ver intentos de conexión a tu servidor en CentOs7?

Tags: linux

Conseguí este comando en un tutorial de CentOs7 y permite generar una lista con el formato:

|`intentos`|`direccion ip`|`usuario ingresado`|

Con el cual puedes conocer los intentos de conexión a tu servidor, la ip que trato de acceder y el usuario que trato de conectar.

El código es el siguiente:

```
zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure* | sed "s/invalid user //" | tr -s " " | awk '{print $11" "$9}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20
```

Mejor visibilidad:

```
zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure* | 
sed "s/invalid user //" | 
tr -s " " | 
awk '{print $11" "$9}' | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sort -rn | 
head -20
```

Quisiera que alguien por favor pudiera explicarme su funcionamiento por etapas, he buscado algunos comandos pero no entiendo aun como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traducido de: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383279/how-does-this-scrip-work-in-centos7

---

**El comando:**

```
zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure*
```

busca en tu registro ubicado en: /var/log/secure log por los intentos fallidos:

```
Aug  1 21:22:53 jbclamp001 sshd[40401]: Failed password for jbutryn from ip.ip.ip.ip port 55843 ssh2
```

---

**El comando::**

```
sed "s/invalid user //"
```

Buscara la frase `"invalid user "` y la reemplazara por `""`.

---

**El comando:**

```
tr -s " "
```

Cortara cada espacio extra u carácter en blanco de la `string`.

---

**El comando:**

```
awk '{print $11" "$9}'
```

Tomara solo la columna `11` y `9` y las mostrara (Estas corresponden al **ip** y al **username**).

---

**El comando:**

```
sort
```

Ordenara los resultados alfa-numéricamente.

---

**El comando:**

```
uniq -c
```

Eliminara cualquier valor duplicado.

---

**El comando:**

```
sort -rn
```

Ordenara la lista de forma reversa numéricamente.

---

**El comando:**

```
head -20
```

Mostrara solo los 20 primeros resultados.

---